# Close an specific activity android

Tags: android, android-activity

Just, How can I close an specific activity of my application?

for example I have the activities:

A1 > B1 > C1

And in C1 I can go to A activity again with new params so when I will open a new B (B2), I want to close older activities: A1, B1, C1.

Being the new result:

A2 > B2

Where I can go back to A2 after of B2, and finish the app from A2.

Comment: You must call finish method in your existing activity right after start a new activity.

Comment: You are approaching this problem wrong. Lookup android `launchMode`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two ways to do this:

You can use activity declaration such as [single top](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html). Or you can pass data between activities using [start for result](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29). Then on [onActivityResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult%28int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent%29) just call `finish();`

Comment: Yes I thought about that and I was checking for other solution, thanks

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
Intent i = new Intent(C.this, A.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
startActivity(i);
```

`FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` will clear all other `Activities` off of the stack. `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK`

> this flag will cause any existing task that would be associated with the activity to be cleared before the activity is started.

[Intent Flags](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)

**Note** as stated by @Dalmas `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` only works for API >= 11

Comment: Note that `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` only works for API >= 11.

Comment: This doesnt work, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP only close A2 and I am developing for API 8 so I will try with other way. Thanks any way!